# why apscheduler use get_jobs empty?

Tags: python-2.7, apscheduler

this is my test.py

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sys
import os

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.jobstores.redis import RedisJobStore

jobstores = {
        #'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite')
        'default': RedisJobStore(host='localhost', port=6379)
}
scheduler = BlockingScheduler(jobstores=jobstores)

def alarm(time):
    print('Alarm! This alarm was scheduled at %s.' % time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    alarm_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10)
    scheduler.add_job(alarm, 'interval', seconds=10, args=[datetime.now()], name='alarm_test')
    print('To clear the alarms, delete the example.sqlite file.')
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

i do python test.py run job successfully

and then use another terminal by putty

```
python
>>> import redis
>>> from test import *
>>> r = redis.Redis()
>>> r.keys()
>>> r.zrange('apscheduler.run_times',0,1)
```

it will find the job id 57841c0ee05249efb466882265f2c495

```
>>> ret = scheduler.get_jobs(jobstore='default')
```

ret is empty
why???

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you started the scheduler before running `get_jobs()`? If not, it will only list tentatively scheduled jobs. That's why you're not seeing the job.

Try this instead:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.redis import RedisJobStore

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_jobstore('redis', host='localhost', port=6379)
scheduler.start(paused=True)
scheduler.print_jobs()
```

Comment: get_jobs must run in same process?
what I am doing is that use 2 terminal  
1. (putty A) python test.py to run the job
2. (putty B) and then use
'''
python
>>> import redis
>>> from test import *
>>> ret = scheduler.get_jobs(jobstore='default')
'''
I want to get_jobs from other terminal

Comment: I've edited the answer to include an alternative script to print the jobs.