# Apscheduler get_jobs() returns empty list

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, apscheduler

Been struggling with this for a while. I have my apscheduler set up with Flask on AWS server with UWSGI. Everything seems to work fine except i cant get a list of scheduled jobs from scheduler.get_jobs(). Also tried scheduler.print_jobs() with the result of "none". Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
scheduler.start()
```

I have one app.route to start the periodic task and then another route to show the scheduled routes. My periodic task starts fine and does what it needs to do (updates my google spreadsheets file) at the right interval.

```
#schedules the job but returns "None"
@app.route("/runscheduler")
def runscheduler():
    with app.app_context():
        job = scheduler.add_job(get_balance, 'interval', seconds=120, id="sfvs")
        return str(scheduler.print_jobs())
```

I tried to create a route that would return scheduler.get_jobs() but that returns an empy list

```
@app.route("/schedule")
def schedule():
    return str(scheduler.get_jobs())
```

Last thing i tried is to get the job info by id in my home route and that actually returns all of the right info:

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return str(scheduler.get_job("sfvs"))
```

returns: get_balance (trigger: interval[0:02:00], next run at: 2021-02-21 03:39:17 UTC)

So my question why cant my code show the list of scheduled jobs (neither scheduler.get_jobs() or scheduler.print_jobs()) but i can still get all of the details of my job by accessing it by id? And on top of all of that the job still executes perfectly fine at the right intervals.

Comment: i guess this should help! https://stackoverflow.com/q/64255088/4915288

Comment: I have already looked through that thread. Main solution was having scheduler.start() before the call of scheduler.get_jobs() which is what i have already. Im not sure .add_jobstore() would solve my problem.

Comment: Could you construct a self contained example that reproduces the problem? That would help a lot.

Comment: You have to ensure that the scheduler has started before adding the job. Please run the scheduler 'on startup' so that it becomes executed in while. Then you can add a job and get jobs.